# Finding duplicate entries with Long Text data type in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a query that returns the following error message upon running it:
**Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery 'field1'**

My query is shown below:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table1
WHERE (((table1.[field1]) In (SELECT [field1] FROM [table1] As Tmp GROUP BY [field1] HAVING Count(*)>1 )))
ORDER BY fie1dl1;
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding CStr to the [field1] value.  Group By Cstr([Field1]).

Comment: Please see the answer from @Cetin as well.  Grouping on a CStr value might truncate it to 255 chars, I don't know if that will work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(writing as an answer just because as a comment it would be a mess - might be an answer if the requirement is provided)

I don't use access, but from the message as I understand grouping on long text is not supported.
As a workaround, if your long text data could be identified in their first 255 characters (access supports 255 in length in short text? to be on the safe side let's say 250):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE left([field1],250) In (SELECT left(field1,250) 
   FROM [table1] 
   GROUP BY left([field1],250) HAVING Count(*) > 1 )
ORDER BY field1;
```

PS: If access have a CheckSum calculating function, then you could use it for comparison instead of Left(field1, 250).